# space between two textboxes in single div

Tags: html, css

I need to give space between two text boxes how much I want. How can I achieve. Below is my code.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Change Password" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Comment: use margin, padding css properties.

Comment: with in text boxes or inside the div?

Comment: you can use `css` style like adding `margin` or `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&nbsp;`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Change Password" />
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-top` property to set space between two text boxes.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2hg95e6g/1/) is the js fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin` to get space between button. `+` selector used for adding margin to the button which was placed immediately after `.btn`.

```css
.btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="Change Password" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `margin-right` inside input field.
Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BpmHyKfagO4qHErY5BHV?p=preview)  hope it will help you.